# Accidental Complexity in OpenSSL HMAC functions

Tags: c++, profiling, thread-safety, openssl, hmac

**SSL Documentation Analaysis**

This question is pertaining the usage of the HMAC routines in OpenSSL.

Since Openssl documentation is a tad on the weak side in certain areas, profiling has revealed that using the:

```
 unsigned char *HMAC(const EVP_MD *evp_md, const void *key,
               int key_len, const unsigned char *d, int n,
               unsigned char *md, unsigned int *md_len);
```

From [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/hmac.html#), shows **40% of my library runtime** is devoted to creating and taking down **HMAC_CTX**'s behind the scenes.

There are also two additional function to create and destroy a **HMAC_CTX** explicetly:

> HMAC_CTX_init() initialises a HMAC_CTX
>   before first use. It must be called.
>
> HMAC_CTX_cleanup() erases the key and
>   other data from the HMAC_CTX and
>   releases any associated resources. It
>   must be called when an HMAC_CTX is no
>   longer required.

These two function calls are prefixed with:

> The following functions may be used if
>   the message is not completely stored
>   in memory

My data fits entirely in memory, so I choose the HMAC function -- the one whose signature is shown above.

The context, as described by the man page, is made use of by using the following two functions:

> HMAC_Update() can be called repeatedly
>   with chunks of the message to be
>   authenticated (len bytes at data).
>
> HMAC_Final() places the message
>   authentication code in md, which must
>   have space for the hash function
>   output.

---

**The Scope of the Application**

My application generates a authentic (HMAC, which is also used a nonce), CBC-BF encrypted protocol buffer string. The code will be interfaced with various web-servers and frameworks Windows / Linux as OS, nginx, Apache and IIS as webservers and Python / .NET and C++ web-server filters.

The description above should clarify that the library needs to be thread safe, and **potentially** have resumeable processing state -- i.e., lightweight threads sharing a OS thread (which might leave thread local memory out of the picture).

---

**The Question**

How do I get rid of the **40% overhead on each invocation** in a (1) thread-safe / (2) resume-able state way ? (2) is optional since I have all of the source-data present in one go, and can make sure a digest is created in place without relinquishing control of the thread mid-digest-creation. So,

(1) can probably be done using thread local memory -- but how do I resuse the CTX's ? does the **HMAC_final()** call make the CTX reusable ?.

(2) optional: in this case I would have to create a pool of CTX's.

(3) how does the HMAC function do this ? does it create a CTX in the scope of the function call and destroy it ?

**Psuedocode and commentary will be useful.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the `HMAC_Init_ex()` function in OpenSSL 0.9.8g says:

> `HMAC_Init_ex()` initializes **or reuses** a
>   `HMAC_CTX` structure to use the function
>   `evp_md` and key `key`. Either can be
>   `NULL`, in which case the existing one
>   will be reused.

(Emphasis mine).  So this means that you can initialise a `HMAC_CTX` with `HMAC_CTX_Init()` once, then keep it around to create multiple HMACs with, as long as you don't call `HMAC_CTX_cleanup()` on it and you start off each HMAC with `HMAC_Init_ex()`.

So yes, you should be able to do what you want with a `HMAC_CTX` in thread-local memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't trying to restrict your dependencies, you could choose a HMAC implementation that is self contained and requires that the user explicitly control all the aspects that OpenSSL is, in it's documentation, vague about. Many such simple C/C++ alternatives exist, but it is up to you to choose and evaluate such an alternative.

Comment: This is indeed true, but I would rather depend on OpenSSL since I am not a cryptography expert, and I don't want to pick up someone else's weak portability / attack surface issues.

Comment: One wonders why you are apparently having a conversation with yourself.

Comment: Well you can answer your own questions, so I thought it appropriate to write it in this ways. Besides I wanted to make sure this answer isn't given :D